# Replacing English Digits with Persian Digits by their Unicode character codes with a condition

Tags: php, unicode

I wrote this PHP Function:

```
<?php   

    function persian_digits($text) {
        $persian_unicode = array(
            "1" => '&#x6F1;',
            "2" => '&#x6F2;',
            "3" => '&#x6F3',
            "4" => '&#x6F4',
            "5" => '&#x6F5',
            "6" => '&#x6F6',
            "7" => '&#x6F7',
            "8" => '&#x6F8',
            "9" => '&#x6F9',
            "0" => '&#x6F0;'
        );
        foreach ($persian_unicode as $key => $value) {
            $text = str_replace($key, $value, $text);
        }
        return $text;
    }
?>
```

When i give an input to it, this function replace all digits to Persian equivalents.
But input have URLs such as `<img src="URL"/>`, When the replace occurs all the URLs and HTML tags get problem with Persian digits.

Please help me find a way to replace English digits with their Persian equivalents in only simple text and not in URLs and HTML tags.
Thanks.
(Sorry for my English)

Comment: I forgot some Semicolons after Unicode Codes! 3 to 9 Digits!

Answer (score 4):

you can use this function

```
function translateDigits($str) {
    $newstring=str_replace(array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'), array('۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹'), $str);
    return $newstring;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this functions:

```
<?php

/* Originally written by Farhadi , www.farhadi.ir */

function convertToFarsi($matches) {
    $mps_jd_optionsDB = get_option(MPS_JD_OPTIONS_NAME);
    $mps_jd_decimal = $mps_jd_optionsDB['mps_jd_decimal'];
    if($mps_jd_decimal == true)
        //$farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "<sub><small>/</small></sub>");
        $farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "٫");
    else
        $farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", ".");

    $english_array = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".");

    $out = '';
    if (isset($matches[1])) {
        return str_replace($english_array, $farsi_array, $matches[1]);
    }
    return $matches[0];
}

function farsi_num($num,$fake = null,$fake2=null) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/(?:&#\d{2,4};)|(\d+[\.\d]*)|(?:[a-z](?:[\x00-\x3B\x3D-\x7F]|<\s*[^>]+>)*)|<\s*[^>]+>/i', 'convertToFarsi', $num);
}

function english_num($num) {
    $mps_jd_optionsDB = get_option(MPS_JD_OPTIONS_NAME);
    $mps_jd_decimal = $mps_jd_optionsDB['mps_jd_decimal'];
    if($mps_jd_decimal == true)
        //$farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "<sub><small>/</small></sub>");
        $farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", "٫");
    else
        $farsi_array = array("۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹", ".");

    $english_array = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", ".");

    return str_replace($farsi_array, $english_array, $num);
}
?>
```